# How to use a dynamic value from child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Considering the following (min) code in a React Remix project (functional components)

```js
<Parent>
  <Child1 />
  <Child2
    <div1></div1>
    <div2></div2>
   />
  <Child3 />
</Parent>
```

I'm successfully getting the height value of div1 (with the ref attatched to it), dynamically, from inside the Child2 component, using `useElementSize()` hook and it looks like this:

```js
const [squareRef, { height }] = useElementSize();

return (
  <section className="flex flex-col w-full">
    <p className="mx-auto text-5xl font-bold">{height}</p>
    <div className="w-full bg-black" ref={squareRef}>
    ...
);
```

But I need to use this height value inside of Parent component, in order to apply conditional styles to Child1 and Child3.
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

I've tried using a `callback` and `lifting up` state, as well as `useContext`, all as per React docs but I think I'm on the wrong track. I also believe I might be over complicating the issue, but I've been stuck for a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you're looking to do here is use the hook you're using inside the parent, [then you will be able to use `React.forwardRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/forwardRef) to pass that ref to the functional component (Child 2), which will then attach that ref to the div you're interested in.

Pretty sure that gives you what you're looking for, ultimately it's React's way to allow you to pass refs down almost like a prop.

From the docs your code will end up looking something like...

```js
// Parent file
const ref = useRef(null) // or whatever hook you want

return <Child2 ref={ref} />


// Child2 file
const Child2 = forwardRef(function Child2(props, ref) {
  ...
  return <div ref={ref}>This is the div I want</div>
});
```